# Laravel Eloquent - $fillable is not working?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have set the variable `$fillable` in my model. I wanted to test the `update` functionality, and I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `positions` set `name` = Casual Aquatic Leader, `_method` = PUT, `id` = 2, `description` = Here is my description, `updated_at` = 2014-05-29 17:05:11 where `positions`.`client_id` = 1 and `id` = 2)"

Why is this yelling at `_method` when my fillable doesn't have that as a parameter? My update function is:

```
Client::find($client_id)
        ->positions()
        ->whereId($id)
        ->update(Input::all());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change following:

```
->update(Input::all());
```

to this (exclude the `_method` from the array)

```
->update(Input::except('_method'));
```

### Update:

Actually following `update` method is being called from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class which is being triggered by `_call` method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations` class (because you are calling the `update` on a relation) and hence the `$fillable` check is not getting performed and you may use `Input::except('_method')` as I answered:

```
public function update(array $values)
{
    return $this->query->update($this->addUpdatedAtColumn($values));
}
```

If you directly call this on a Model (Not on a relation):

```
Positions::find($id)->update(Input::all());
```

Then this will not happen because `fillable` check will be performed within `Model.php` because following `update` method will be called from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class:

```
public function update(array $attributes = array())
{
    if ( ! $this->exists)
    {
        return $this->newQuery()->update($attributes);
    }

    return $this->fill($attributes)->save();
}
```

Comment: This was my initial test Postman. In reality, I have a lot of other keys being sent. The whole point of this `$fillable` is so that I don't have to do that!

Comment: How did you use/set `fullable` property and where is it?

Comment: Inside my model file I have `protected $fillable = array('name', 'show_order', 'description');`

Comment: Do you have also `$guarded` property declared in your model?

Comment: No I don't. Do I need to?

Answer (score 0):

write a parent class

```
class BaseModel extends Model

public static function getFillableAttribute(Model $model, $data){
    $array = $model->getFillable();
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($array as $item){
        if( isset($data["$item"])){
            $arr["$item"] = $data["$item"];
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this breaking after updating from Laravel 5.2 to 5.4 - I can't find anything in the documentation / migration guide that covers it.

As covered in this [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2063) the correct fix/use of Eloquent seems to be:

```
Positions::find($id)->fill(Input::all())->save();
```

To trigger the `fillable` check by laravel and then perist the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this

```php
$data = request()->all();
//remove them from the array
unset($data['_token'],$data['_method']);
//then
Client::find($client_id)
        ->positions()
        ->whereId($id)
        ->update($data);
```

This removes the `_method` and `_token` from the array