# Laravel Update model automatically with Validator Data?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering if it was possible to update/save a model with the validator data? I've tried googling and can't seem to find anything.

I'm just trying to do something like this

```
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'address_line_1' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'address_line_2' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'postcode' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'county' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    ]);

    $address = $validator->getData();
    $address->save();
```

rather then having to set all the variables one by one and then saving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `getData()` returns an associative array, you can use the `update` method:

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
    'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'address_line_1' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'address_line_2' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'postcode' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'county' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
]);

$address->update($validator->getData());
```

Or (in my opinion), you can make use od the `validate` method of `request` that returns the validated data (if validation is successful)

```
$address->update(request()->validate([
    'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'address_line_1' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'address_line_2' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'postcode' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'county' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
]));
```

Be aware that (depending on which version of Laravel are you using) in order to perform those types of operations, you might have to disable guard for those fields in the `Model`:

```
class ... extends Model{
     protected $guarded = [];
     // or
     protected $fillable = [/*list of attributes*/]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this if you want

Create

```
$address = Address::create($request->all());
```

Update

```
$address = Address::update($request->all());
```

This will do your job as you wanted to.

But you need to be careful about the `mass assignment`(don't forget to read the `NOTE` below)

If you perform mass assignment(the solution that I wrote above), you shouldn't take any risks. Therefore, in your model set `fillable` or `guarded` property accordingly.

You can read about it in detail over here.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

**NOTE:**
But the `fillable` check doesn't work with the `update` in a few scenarios.

It will perform the fillable check

```
Model::update([..]);
```

It won't perform the check in this case.

```
Model::where('attribute', 'some value')->update([..]);
```

These references have a detailed explanation to this behavior.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16447

[Laravel Eloquent - $fillable is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945040/laravel-eloquent-fillable-is-not-working)

Comment: Yes, you can do the same with the update as well. But when update is called, it doesn't perform the fillable check. Here's the reason why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945040/laravel-eloquent-fillable-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 I find this way more concise and easy:

```php
class StoreEntityRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2'],
            'age' => ['required', 'number'],
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
class EntityController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreEntityRequest $request, Entity $entity){
        $entity->update(
            $request->safe()->toArray()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you could also use $request->validated() instead of $request->safe()->toArray()